# Understanding copy-constructor in a CRTP example

Tags: c++, copy-constructor

I'm trying to understand a simple use-case of CRTP. Here is the example from [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern#Object_counter)

```
template <typename T>
struct counter
{
    static int objects_created;
    static int objects_alive;

    counter()
    {
        ++objects_created;
        ++objects_alive;
    }

    counter(const counter&)
    {
        ++objects_created;
        ++objects_alive;
    }
protected:
    ~counter() // objects should never be removed through pointers of this type
    {
        --objects_alive;
    }
};
template <typename T> int counter<T>::objects_created( 0 );
template <typename T> int counter<T>::objects_alive( 0 );

class X : counter<X>
{
    // ...
};
```

I didn't understand the copy contstructor. Why did they do incrementing in it? Moreover, I removed it and the example worked as well **[**[***DEMO***](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2d46b76d957eb5b7)**]**. Why did they declare it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I didn't understand the copy contstructor. Why did they do incrementing in it?

An object constructed by invoking the copy constructor should be counted as an object constructed.

Your example works since it does not use the copy constructor.

Use:

```
X x;
X xx(x);
```

to see the difference.

Answer (score 1):

Otherwise, the copy constructor would be generated by default but would not count the created objects, as in case of

```
X x1;
X x2(x1);
```

Yes, demo works without it, but does not count objects in the correct manner.